# How to extract the XML from a log entry?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, logs, xml

We are logging XML messages to a downstream system in our logs.

I am trying to use `sed` to extract the XML from the log entry, but not sure exactly how to use it.

This is a typical log entry:

`2018-02-20T10:02:51.395Z|hostname1|user1||Application Name||10062|DEBUG|o.s.i.channel.DirectChannel||postSend (sent=true) on channel 'logger', message: GenericMessage [payload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><canonMessage xmlns="somenamespace">...the message body...</canonMessage>, headers={quote_format=FpML, id=f572ea65-91dd-a610-7976-5a1e97c16524, quote_message_id=b640bd90-1624-11e8-a904-bd3c0f5af83b_1519120971176, quote_data=Quote Rep, quote_transaction_originator=user1, timestamp=1519120971394}]`

How could I strip the front and end of the log entry from the XML?

The output from `sed` for the above line should be:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><canonMessage xmlns="somenamespace">...the message body...</canonMessage>`

Comment: Kindly post the expected output

Comment: `grep -o '<?xml.*</canonMessage>' /path/to/log` should do the trick.

Comment: @DopeGhoti can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -o '<?xml.*</canonMessage>' /path/to/log` should do the trick.

The `-o` option for `grep` tells it *only* output data which match the provided regular expression.  Happily, you're only talking here about *extracting* (partial) XML, not *parsing* it.

Comment: Yes this worked for me. For parsing I would use XSLT, which just involves piping the XML output to another process (

Answer (score 0):

I got the above mentioned output by using below mentioned sed command

```
sed  "s/.*payload=//g" input.xml | sed "s/,.*//g"
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><canonMessage xmlns="somenamespace">...the message body...</canonMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use sed instead of [grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425462/117549), you could have it do a search & replace and only print only if it matched something:

```
sed -n 's%.*\(<?xml .*</canonMessage>\).*%\1%p' < input
```

Here we are `-n`ot printing lines by default, then do a search-and-replace of the `<?xml ...</canonMessage>` text; the escaped parenthesis around that text "capture" it into numbered slots. By adding greedy `.*` regex captures before and after the desired XML text, we can replace the entire line with the saved text in `\1` and then print the resulting line.

I used `%` to separate the search-text and replacement-text because the `</canonMessage>` has the typical forward-slash separator in it. If you like the forward-slash separator better, you'd just have to escape the one you're trying to match:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(<?xml .*<\/canonMessage>\).*/\1/p' < input
```